# I don't know which device I need to port forward on my network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

Ever since my IT guy quit I do not know how my network is set up. I am not sure if this is the place to ask about networking since this site is usually used for coding.

Anyway I am having trouble with port forwarding to my laptop and have no idea which device i must forward and where I need to go to do so. UPnP doesn't work and I am trying to work around by manually port forwarding so I can connect to a friends LAN Gaming server.

Here is my setup...and I dont know too much about networking. I'm not sure what is what but I have a large Arris TM6026/115 and an Arris Touchstone SB6183.

I also have a TP-Link TL-SF1008P 8 port 10/100 Mbps Desktop PoE switch, and a TP-Link Safe Stream TL-R600VPN Digital Broadband VPN Router.

Then I have 2 EnGenius access points with WAP01 xx.xx.xx.xx and WAP02 xx.xx.xx.xx numbered labels.

I think the arris is modem with tp-link routers and the engenius are just for access throughout my house.

Which box will be doing the port forwarding, and where do I go to open the ports? I believe the TP-Link VPN Router will be doing the port forwarding but I wasn't sure with so many boxes and the access points which device was actually doing the job of my router.

Thanks

Comment: Hi - We need the make and model of every device including the "unlabeled black device".  We also need to know what you will be using port forwarding for.  Port forwarding is usually configured at the router to allow you to access your inside devices from outside.

Comment: more importantly what service are you trying to forward.  For example you have a web server on your laptop and other people on the internet are trying to reach that web server.

Comment: @Keltari - One step at a time boss! He's got networking literacy problems :-)

Comment: Typically routers are where you set port forwarding. Regarding the "web address", besides exact makes and models (as already requested), you will probably need to edit your question with what network(s) you have available (e.g. 192.168.x.x, 10.0.x.x, etc.) as well.

Comment: @pythonian that should be the FIRST step.  knowing what he is trying to accomplish is far more important than what is on his network.

Comment: Ya! That's my 2nd ask boss!

Comment: Ill be your I.T guy. ;)

Comment: Ok I have edited the question with make and models and I am trying to port forward in order to connect to a friends LAN server

Comment: In order to connect to your "friend's LAN server" (??), supposedly from outside their network (???), it's your friend, not you, who has to have the proper port forwarding. Please consider posting a question about what you want to do/achieve instead. That you don't know what you're doing is perfectly clear already. I hope that you know, at least, what do you want to do/achieve so we can actually help you with that.

Comment: I am trying to play a game through a lan game client and my security won't let me play through my firewall. I obviously want to keep the firewall on so I am trying to open the correct port to connect to the server. If I put my IP address in browser will I be able to edit my router and which devices IP address would i need?

Comment: In other words how do i find my routers ip address? I think if i put that in my browser I can port forward there from what I've read, but I have found tons of different ip addresses so now I'm confused. Is it my default gateway its a 10.xx.xx.x not the usual 192.xx... which is weird

Comment: And when i type the default gateway10.xx... ip number into my web address i get nothing. I need the port settings page. If I have that It should solve everything. I'm trying to do this https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-134.html but as I said the 10.xx... gives me a cannot display page

Comment: @nathaniel ratliff, Windows = "start > cmd > ipconfig /all" Linux = ifconfig from the terminal. It will be labeled as the default gateway. No one will come back to your comments if you don't use the (@username), it notifies us of comments directed towards us.